# what does this unusual python (or shell?) idiom mean? "!mv {path} {path}.png"

Tags: python, idioms

```
!mv {path} {path}.png
```

This is one line from python script. What does this mean?
I've never seen this before.

There is also something similar in the code:

```
!/some/path/not-string-just-as-it-is-here.png
```

Seems like some kind of string manipulation (formatting?) instruction ...or what?

Comment: That's not Python. It looks like it could be an IPython magic command, though.

Comment: as the person before me said, that looks like an iPython magic command. They invoke terminal commands and return the output

Comment: Yes! Thanks for direction! I don't have any experiences with IPython, so I don't know about any kind of IPython magic commands.

Answer (score 0):

You can learn about Jupyter Notebooks (formerly known as IPython Notebooks) from the [official documentation](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

The specific syntax you are facing is explained [here](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/tutorial.html#system-shell-commands) and is indeed just a way to execute shell commands in the Jupyter run-time environment.